# Appending D3.js Elements to Shadow DOM of Polymer Element

Tags: d3.js, polymer, shadow-dom

I'm working on a Polymer (v1) project and one of my custom polymer elements needs to contain a D3 (v4) chart. D3 seems to operate pretty heavily on appending to the DOM. Unfortunately, Polymer seems pretty strict about how DOM manipulation is performed.

I have created a very simple version of the D3 chart I want to implement:

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .bar {
            fill: #0198E1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<svg></svg>

<script>
var data = [100, 120, 130, 110, 150, 90];

const CHART_WIDTH = 126;
const CHART_HEIGHT = 160;

svg = d3.select('svg')
    .attr("width", CHART_WIDTH)
    .attr("height", CHART_HEIGHT);

svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data).enter().append('rect')
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {return i * 21})
        .attr("y", function(d) {return CHART_HEIGHT - d})
        .attr("height", function(d) {return d})
        .attr("width", 20)
        .attr("class", "bar");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have attempted two solutions with the following files.

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="./d3-chart.html">
</head>
<body>
    <d3-chart></d3-chart>
</body>
</html>
```

***d3-lib.html***

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

## Attempted Solution 1

Use a combination of D3 and Polymer to select the target svg element and then perform d3 appends.

***d3-chart.html***

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="./d3-lib.html">

<dom-module id="d3-chart">
    <template>
        <style>
           .bar {
               fill: #0198E1;
           }
        </style>

        <svg id="svg"></svg>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'd3-chart',
            properties: {
                data: {
                    Type: Array,
                    value: [100, 120, 130, 110, 150, 90]
                }
            },
            ready: function() {
                const CHART_WIDTH = 126;
                const CHART_HEIGHT = 160;

                var svg = d3.select(this.$.svg)
                    .attr("width", CHART_WIDTH)
                    .attr("height", CHART_HEIGHT);

                svg.selectAll('rect')
                    .data(this.data).enter().append('rect')
                        .attr("x", function(d, i) {return i * 21})
                        .attr("y", function(d) {return CHART_HEIGHT - d})
                        .attr("height", function(d) {return d})
                        .attr("width", 20)
                        .attr("class", "bar");
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

This successfully displays the chart but the css style doesn't apply. I assume this is because Polymer doesn't 'know' about the new elements that have been appended.

## Attempted Solution 2

Use D3 to select a new svg element (not in the DOM), perform D3 appends on the element, and use Polymer to append it to the DOM.

***d3-chart.html***

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="./d3-lib.html">

<dom-module id="d3-chart">
    <template>
        <style>
           .bar {
               fill: #0198E1;
           }
        </style>

    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'd3-chart',
            properties: {
                data: {
                    Type: Array,
                    value: [100, 120, 130, 110, 150, 90]
                }
            },
            ready: function() {
                const CHART_WIDTH = 126;
                const CHART_HEIGHT = 160;

                var newSvgElement = document.createElement("svg");

                var svg = d3.select(newSvgElement)
                    .attr("width", CHART_WIDTH)
                    .attr("height", CHART_HEIGHT);

                svg.selectAll('rect')
                    .data(this.data).enter().append('rect')
                        .attr("x", function(d, i) {return i * 21})
                        .attr("y", function(d) {return CHART_HEIGHT - d})
                        .attr("height", function(d) {return d})
                        .attr("width", 20)
                        .attr("class", "bar");

                Polymer.dom(this.root).appendChild(newSvgElement);
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

This code successfully appends all elements to the DOM but nothing is displayed.

What is the proper way to integrate Polymer with D3?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. I just had to add the following line to the beginning of the ready function in 'Attempted Solution 1'.

```
this.scopeSubtree(this.$.svg, true);
```

For more information:
[Why is my SVG rendered by D3 inside a Polymer component unstyled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34345957/why-is-my-svg-rendered-by-d3-inside-a-polymer-component-unstyled)